# Compute bit parity in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu, parity

CUDA has *popcount* intrinsics for 32-bit and 64-bit types: `__popc()` and `__popcll()`.

Does CUDA also have intrinsics to get the **parity** of 32-bit and 64-bit types? 
(The **parity** refers to whether an integer has an even or odd amount of 1-bits.)

For example, GCC has `__builtin_parityl()` for 64-bit integers.

And here's a C function that does the same thing:

```
inline uint parity64(uint64 n){
  n ^= n >> 1;
  n ^= n >> 2;
  n  = (n & 0x1111111111111111lu) * 0x1111111111111111lu;
  return (n >> 60) & 1;
}
```

Comment: can't you just take the popcount and determine if that number is even or odd, i.e. `__popcll(n) & 1` ?

Comment: The [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html) doesn't list *bit parity* as an intrinsic, so I may have to go with your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a parity [intrinsic for CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html).

However you should be able to create a fairly simple function to do it using either the [`__popc()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1g43c9c7d2b9ebf202ff1ef5769989be46) (32-bit unsigned case) or [`__popcll()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1g6bb2f1cc3495f3f2ebe1df6ec52b3aec) (64-bit unsigned case) intrinsics.

For example, the following function should indicate whether the number of 1 bits in a 64-bit unsigned quantity is odd (true) or even (false):

```
__device__ bool my_parity(unsigned long long d){
  return (__popcll(d) & 1);}
```